# How to obtain final STATUS from a text sent to mobile phone

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

I am sending a text to a mobile number (US phone number) using the Programmable Messaging Quickstart for C# with .NET Core example. The message is sent and received successfully but the STATUS in the response shows "queued".
Is there a sample callback in C# to obtain the final status after the text is sent?

Answer (score 1):

You have 3 options, either of the first two are suggested.

1. Subscribe to [statusCallbacks](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/api/message-resource#statuscallback-request-parameters), which will alert your application of the delivery status of the send message.
2. Use [Event Streams](https://www.twilio.com/docs/events) to subscribe to specific message delivery event types (this option provides the ability to select different types of message delivery events).
3. Less efficient and not very scalable, make a request to the [/Messages endpoint](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/api/message-resource#fetch-a-message-resource) to determine the final disposition of the sent message (via its unique message SID).

[Best Practices for SMS Message Logging](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/outbound-message-logging)